# why InterlockedAdd is not available in vs2010?

Tags: c++, c, windows, visual-studio-2010, interlocked

I have include windows.h and want to use InterlockedAdd in vs2010 and compiles error "identifier not found", but the `InterlockedIncrement` can work well. I try to use:

```
#include <intrin.h>
#pragma intrinsic(_InterlockedAdd)
```

and compiles error:

> warning C4163: '_InterlockedAdd' : not available as an intrinsic function
>   1>test10.cpp(107): error C3861: 'InterlockedAdd': identifier not found

What's wrong with the code?

Comment: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/524100/interlockedadd-is-where seems to talk about it

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `InterlockedAdd` function is only available on the Itanium platform. On x86 and x86-64 platforms you can use `InterlockedExchangeAdd` instead. This also adds a value to the target variable, but it returns the original value instead of the new value.